# Clear Android GMail search history programmatically

Tags: search, gmail, history

I'm trying to clear the GMail search history, but it's not working. How should I approach this?

```
SearchRecentSuggestions xxx =                           
            new SearchRecentSuggestions(getBaseContext(), "com.google.android.gm.SearchHistoryProvider", 1);

xxx.clearHistory();
```

Comment: have u resolved your query ?